# GraphQLList custom type returns mongodb fields as null

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I am using mongodb in node.js and I am trying to return a field that is a list of custom objects. I've tried both with and without 'toArray()' on the end of the query but that doesn't seem to change the result

I have a custom type my GraphQL schema looks roughly like (less the code for the root store/viewer etc)

```
let addressType = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'Address',
   fields: () => ({
      addressType: {type: GraphQLString, resolve: (obj) => obj.AddressType },
      addressLineOne: {type: GraphQLString, resolve: (obj) => obj.AddressLineOne}
   });
});

let userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'User',
   fields: () => ({
      CustomId: {type: GraphQLID, resolve: (obj) => obj.CustomID},
      name: {type: GraphQLString},
      addresses: {
         type: GraphQLList(addressType),
         resolve: (user) => {
            let findParams = {
               CustomID: user.CustomID
            };

            let returnParams = {
               USER_ADDRESSES: 1
            }

            return db.collection("User").find(findParams, returnParams).toArray();
         }
      }
   })
});
```

My mongo document looks like...

```
"Name":"Joe",
"CustomID":"12345",
"USER_ADDRESSES": 
[
   {
      "AddressType" : "Home",
      "AddressLineOne" : "123 Maple st"
   },
   {
      "AddressType" : "AlternateAddress",
      "AddressLineOne" : "456 Main St"
   }
]
```

Just using graphiql to test the schema the query looks like

```
{
   store{
      user(CustomID:"12345"){
         name,
         addresses {
            addressType,
            addressLineOne
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which is returning ...

```
{
   "data":{
      "store": {
         "user": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "addresses" : [
               "addressType": null,
               "addressLineOne": null
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `obj` in the addressType resolver? It's obviously returning something (otherwise there would be no list in the result), but apparently not what you expect.

Comment: So if in the first field addressType: {type: GraphQLString, resolve: (obj) => obj.AddressType } .... I change it to addressType: {type: GraphQLString, resolve: (obj) => {console.log(obj); obj.AddressType }}, I am getting all of the addresses but it is in a format like {[{AddressType:"Home" ....},{...}]}